# Search for files that contain pattern

Tags: grep, find

I have this search - I would like to print out the paths of files that contain the matching text:

```
grep -r  "jasmine" .
```

and it yields results that look like this:

```
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:- [Jasmine Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/jasmine-js)
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:- [Jasmine-dev Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/jasmine-js-dev)
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:git clone git@github.com:yourUserName/jasmine.git              # Clone your fork
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:cd jasmine                                                     # Change directory
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:git remote add upstream https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine.git # Assign original repository to a remote named 'upstream'
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:Note that Jasmine tests itself. The files in `lib` are loaded first, defining the reference `jasmine`. Then the files in `src` are loaded, defining the reference `j$`. So there are two copies of the code loaded under test.
./app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/jasmine-core/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md:The tests should always use `j$` to refer to the objects and functions that are being tested. But the tests can use functions on `jasmine` as needed. _Be careful how you structure any new test code_. Copy the patterns you see in the existing code - this ensures that the code you're testing is not leaking into the `jasmine` reference and vice-versa.
```

But I just want the file names, I don't want to print out the matching contents, *just the file names*, how can I do that?

The problem is that the matching text will wrap around in the terminal and make the results basically unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the `-l` flag from `grep`?

> -l, --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.

A simple search on my home directory,

```
grep -rl 'bash' .
./.bashrc
./.bash_history
./.bash_logout
./.bash_profile
./.profile
./.viminfo
```

---

As a matter of fact, `-l` is a [`POSIX` defined option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) for `grep` should be available in almost all distros.

Comment: Havent tested it yet, will give it a go today